# why we use ##*/ expression with bash variable

Tags: bash

I am tring to understand the bash script.
I am seeing ##* / expression with bash variable.
i.e ${foo##*/}
Can someone please tell me why we use that expression?

Comment: Just do `man bash` and read about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "Parameter expansion". The variable `$foo` is searched for a substring matching the pattern `*/` (i.e. anything up to a slash) from the beginning (`#`), and what remains in the variable is returned. Doubling the `#`-sign makes the matching greedy, i.e. it tries to find the longest possible match.

Comment: thanks for explaining Doubling the #-sign as well